# How do i delete instances of a class from within it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in my case, I have a class `Gnome` for example and I want to destroy each object of this class when its variable `health` reaches 0. Is there a way for me to delete each instance of `Gnome` when its hp is 0 or should I "mark it for death" and delete everything that was marked? Either way, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy each object" or "delete each instance"? What specific behaviour do you associate with that? What should happen to references to these objects? What should happen to containers including these objects? Note that the object lifetime is an implementation detail in Python.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought that u literally delete it from the memory (eg. del Gnome1 -- but this needs to happend automaticly) if it helps

Comment: ``del Gnome1`` does not delete an object from memory, it clears the name ``Gnome1``. Again, what *behaviour* do you expect for references to the deleted object? Should containers still point to the deleted memory, or forget about it? What would references to the object see when trying to do something? Would they see corrupted memory, cleared (`NULL`?) memory, arbitrary memory, or the old memory content?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do what you're wanting.  Every Python object maintains a record of how many references there are to it.  Once the reference count reaches 0, the Python garbage collector will clean it up.

As long as you still have references to the instances, they will persist.

Comment: Reference counting is an implementation detail of CPython - other implementations use different schemes to determine the lifetime of objects. Using ``weakref``, it *is* possible to have references to objects without extending their lifetime.